# Does Google provide some server side SOAP toolkit?

Tags: soap

Does Google provide some server side SOAP toolkit?

Comment: Wanna be a little more specific?

Comment: I think the best person to ask would be google.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are plenty. In the Java space there are JAX-WS RI, Apache Axis 1 and 2 and many others, for example.

Many client-side toolkits also provide some server-side support.

Comment: Has this question always been about Google? I don't remember reading that before. If so: ignore my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What programming language and server are you using?